# Use Jolokia JVM agent directly in a Maven Java project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, javaagents, jolokia

I have a simple Java Maven project and want to use the JVM agent from [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) to fetch JMX values.
It works when I manually download the [jolokia-jvm-1.1.5-agent.jar](http://labs.consol.de/maven/repository/org/jolokia/jolokia-jvm/1.1.5/jolokia-jvm-1.1.5-agent.jar) and add the absolute path to the java-arguments like `-javaagent:/absolute/path/to/jolokia-jvm-1.1.5-agent.jar`.

As the [Jolokia Download page](http://www.jolokia.org/download.html) also lists maven dependencies (`jolokia-core`) I wonder if I can include this directly into my Maven build without manually downloading the JVM agent? How can I run my program with this javaagent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start the Jolokia JVM agent programatically, too. The entry point is  `org.jolokia.jvmagent.JolokiaServer` (to be found in the module `jolokia-jvm`). Please refer to the source, there is quite some documentation there.

Or if you are using Spring, there is even a easier solution. Simply include the Jolokia Spring config XSD and declare the agent bean in the Spring application context. More can be found in the [reference manual](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/jmx.html#jvm-spring).

Finally if you have web you could also declare the Jolokia servlet in you web.xml. See also [here](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html#agent-war-programmatic) for the details.

When you want to automatically download the agent, you could add the Maven dependency with the classifier   `agent`.

If you need further assitance please come to the [Jolokia Forum](http://www.jolokia.org/forum.html) and describe your use case there (think that is the proper place for concrete Jolokia questions).

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer and the great Jolokia :-)! `JolokiaServer` is exactly what I need and didn't know before about it.